# Transfer Learning using Keras and vgg16 on small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, face-recognition

I have to build a neural network that can recognize the face of 15 people. I'm using keras. My dataset is composed of 300 total images and is divided into Training, Validation and Test. For each of the 15 people I have the following subdivision:

- Training: 13
- Validation: 3
- Test: 4

Since I couldn't build an efficient neural network from scratch, I also believe because my dataset is very small, I'm trying to solve my problem by doing transfer learning. I used the vgg16 network. In the training and validation phase I get good results but when I run the tests the results are disastrous.

I don't know what my problem is. Here is the code I used:

```py
img_width, img_height = 256, 256
train_data_dir = 'dataset_biometria/face/training_set'
validation_data_dir = 'dataset_biometria/face/validation_set'
nb_train_samples = 20   
nb_validation_samples = 20 
batch_size = 16
epochs = 5

model = applications.VGG19(weights = "imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3))

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#Adding custom Layers 
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(15, activation="softmax")(x)

# creating the final model 
model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)

# compile the model 
model_final.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])

# Initiate the train and test generators with data Augumentation 
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale = 1./255,
horizontal_flip = True,
fill_mode = "nearest",
zoom_range = 0.3,
width_shift_range = 0.3,
height_shift_range=0.3,
rotation_range=30)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale = 1./255,
horizontal_flip = True,
fill_mode = "nearest",
zoom_range = 0.3,
width_shift_range = 0.3,
height_shift_range=0.3,
rotation_range=30)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
batch_size = batch_size, 
class_mode = "categorical")

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_data_dir,
target_size = (img_height, img_width),
class_mode = "categorical")

# Save the model according to the conditions  
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')


# Train the model 
model_final.fit_generator(
train_generator,
samples_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = validation_generator,
nb_val_samples = nb_validation_samples,
callbacks = [checkpoint, early])

model('model_face_classification.h5')
```

I also tried to train some layers instead of not training any, as in the example below:

```py
for layer in model.layers[:10]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

I also tried changing the number of epochs, batch size, nb_validation_samples, nb_validation_sample.

Unfortunately the result has not changed, in the testing phase my network cannot correctly recognize faces.

Comment: Try using the Adam optimizer. SGD can either overshoot the minima or oscillate around a local minima.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual results or errors I can not say what the problem is here.
Definitely, small dataset is a problem, but there are many ways to get around it.
You can use image augmentation to increase the samples. You can refer [augement.py](https://github.com/ASH1998/Augmentation-of-ODIA-Hand-Written-Dataset/blob/master/augment.py).

But instead of modifying your above network, there is a really cool model : `siamese network/one-shot learning`. It does not need too many pics and the accuracies are great.

Therefore you can see below links to get some help :

1. [Facial-Recognition-Using-FaceNet-Siamese-One-Shot-Learning](https://github.com/mohitwildbeast/Facial-Recognition-Using-FaceNet-Siamese-One-Shot-Learning)
2. [Face-recognition-using-deep-learning](https://github.com/sumantrajoshi/Face-recognition-using-deep-learning)

Comment: Put the folder or directory path into the code as well. This error means the script can't find the required directory of images

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I downloaded the folder from the first link, I installed the required packages but when I try to start the file face_recognizer.py the terminal tells me this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "face_recognizer.py", line 24, in <module>
     for image in os.listdir (os.path.join ('images', name)):
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'images / .DS_Store'